# Regular expressions for removing repeated letters with spaces in java

Tags: java, regex

I need some help understanding regular expressions please. I'm trying to build some chat filters to remove spam.

So far I have `(?<!'|\w|\s)(^[a-z]$)(?!\w|\s)` which will remove 'a'

and `(?<!'|\w|\s)(.)\1{3,}(?!\w|\s)` which will catch 'aaaa'

Where I need help is finding one that will catch 'a a a a a a a a a a a a'

Can some please steer me in the correct direction? Thank you very much.

Comment: *"I'm trying to build some chat filters to remove spam*" Already lost battle.

Comment: How about just `(.*?)(?>\1+)`

Comment: @CAustin according to my regex tester that doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, slight mistake.  It should use a `+` instead of a `*`, so: `(.+?)(?>\1+)`.  What happens when you delete whatever this pattern matches?  It should just leave behind a single copy of the repeated string. http://regex101.com/r/aA4wI6

Comment: @CAustin that appears to work, but it also takes out valid words like 'school', any way around that? Testing with http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Comment: Yeah, in that case things will have to get a bit trickier.  Give this one a try: `^(.+?) ?(?>(?:\1| )+)$`

Comment: @CAustin That seems to work. Please write it up as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the comment above, this pattern should be what you're looking for:

`^(.+?) ?(?>(?:\1| )+)$`